# link server SQL transaction scope not working

Tags: sql-server, transactionscope, msdtc

I am not able to use the connection within the transactionscope It is displaying the error

MSDTC on "server" is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Enable “Distributed Transaction Coordinator” in SQL Server using the path
Start -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tool -> Services

And select the service "Distributed Transaction Coordinator"